# Is there a pattern or trick to force evaluation on both expressions in an OR conditional statement?

Tags: c#, java, c++, design-patterns

What is the best way (pattern) around `return method1() || method2()` not invoking `method2()` if `method1()` returns `true`?

**Example**

I'm using this class to bound a table:

```
class Bounds {
    // return true iff bounds changed
    boolean set(int start, int end);
}
```

and I want this function to resize both the rows and columns and return true iff either was modified:

```
public boolean resizeToFirstCell(Bounds rows, Bounds columns) {
   return rows.set(0, 1) || columns.set(0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Using local variables to store each result should work.

Comment: @delnan I am aware, but what pattern/rewrite would you suggest for clarity while keeping brevity in mind?

Comment: @Vaugn gave you a pattern. With half a dozen programming languages listed you should be lucky to get something that always works, and is clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a non-short circuiting (sometimes called "Eager") operator, `|`.

```
public boolean resizeToFirstCell(Bounds rows, Bounds columns) {
    return rows.set(0, 1) | columns.set(0, 1);
}
```

You can read more about that in the [operator documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for `||` (C# specific link, but still holds true for Java and C++).

Comment: I cannot believe I didnt know this! I am no expert or anything but it seems so basic.. just goes to show its still worth checking out the documentation for things like this!

Comment: I thought that the single symbol versions were for bit wise operations.. I will have to go and read more about them, thanks!

Comment: @gordatron: You are correct, they are for bitwise ops. I believe in C++ this would work by first promoting the bools to ints (false=0, true=1) then doing the bitwise OR on those ints. I presume its the same in C# and Java. It's kind of hacky, but it works, and is used a lot in performance sensitive code where branches due to && and || are expensive.

Comment: Note that this is not exactly the same thing...  It assumes that `set` returns a `bool` (or 0/1).  @Scott Urban's solution is a more reliable pattern in general, plus it is easier to read.  (If you insist on this shortcut formulation, `!!rows.set() | !!columns.set()` is a reliable pattern.)

Comment: @PeterAlexander The link vcsjones posts (MSDN || Operator Reference) says: "x || y corresponds to the operation x | y except that if x is true, y is not evaluated".. 

If the values were not bools (e.g. ints) it would have some unexpected results.

Comment: @gordatron To be fair, the question is also tagged C++, and PeterAlexander's comments are correct (as is Nemo's). I authored this answer mostly around the fact that C# and Java have strict boolean data types.

Comment: oh I agree they are valid, I was more wondering if the MSDN docs were keeping it simple, the evaluation as bit wise is how I was understanding it.. to do the bit wise or you need both values so it makes sense. (my ref to the fact that it might go awry with ints was kind of hinting at that)

Comment: @Nemo is !! = not not? and if so does that guarantee that it is a bool? (sorry for the million comments, tried to google it and go nowhere) oh, and is that specific to one of the mentioned languages? (as in it looks nice in c# as you will get an error on the !! if the value is not a bool but would you still use it in C to give a hint to those editing the code)

Comment: @gordatron:  Yes, `!!` is "not not".  It will map zero to zero and non-zero to one, which is what you need to use logical `|` in general.  (So it is more than a hint...  `x || y` and `x | y` compute different things in general.  `!!x | !!y` computes the same thing as `x || y` but without short-circuiting.)  But again, @Scott Urban's answer is just as correct, just as fast, and easier to read.  It is really a much better answer in every way.  (Note also that this answer does not necessarily preserve evaluation order, either.)

Comment: @Nemo Thanks, I thought it might be something like that (for a *less* type safe languages)

Comment: @Nemo it is exactly the same thing except for the short-circuiting. || requires boolean operands, so any code that used || can be altered to use |.

Comment: @EJP: In C/C++, `||` does not require Boolean operands.  Also, `||` guarantees left-to-right evaluation; `|` does not (again, in C/C++; I do not know about C# or Java).

Comment: This does not work in Java as "|" is the bit wise _or_ operator.

Comment: @AngelO'Sphere Yes, it does work in Java. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation#Support_in_common_programming_languages

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of that. Completely counter intuitive. Since when does that work?

Answer (score 7):

```
public boolean resizeToFirstCell(Bounds rows, Bounds columns) {
    // Intermediate values are used to explicitly avoid short-circuiting.
    bool rowSet = rows.set(0, 1);
    bool columnSet = columns.set(0, 1);
    return rowSet || columnSet;
}
```

Comment: I would also comment this so no one maintains it into the || version as it could seem more readable

Comment: Nobody who understands the programming language would change it into the version using ||.

Comment: @zvrba: What about the people that don't understand the programming language :-)  They do exist!

Comment: It's less about understanding the programming language and more about not realizing `columns.set(0, 1)` *must* execute ;)

Comment: +1; this is much clearer and much less hackish than are the bit-wise or solutions.

Comment: Given that C++ is thrown into the mix of tags, I'd opt for this answer as well. +1.

Comment: "What about the people that don't understand the programming language" - they don't get commit rights, so they can do what they like :-)

Comment: In C++, he could write `rows.set(0,1)+columns.set(0,1)` ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a "pattern" that scales well for more statements:

```
bool fun() {
    bool changed = false;
    changed |= rows.set(0, 1);
    chnaged |= columns.set(0, 1);
    return changed;
}
```

Comment: +1 I like this for the scaling, although my problem primarily is function scaling (many resize functions).  If you have an answer for that as well that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the | eager evaluation instead of shortcircuit operator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation